# Check proof of union of denumerable sets is denumerable too

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove:

> If $A$ and $B$ are denumerable sets then so is their union $A\cup B$.

In this case, denumerable is defined as:

> A set $X$ is said to be denumerable if there is a bijection $\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow X$.

---

My attempt:

$A \text{ denumerable } \implies  f:\mathbb{Z^+} \rightarrow A$

$B \text{ denumerable } \implies  g:\mathbb{Z^+} \rightarrow B$

I need to construct a bijective function, $h:\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow A\cup B$.

So, define $h$:

$h(i)=\left\{ \begin{align}
& f(n+1), & \text{ if } i=2n+1, \text{ for } n \in \{0,1,2,\dots\} \\
& g(n), & \text{ if } i=2n, \text{ for } n \in \{ 1,2,3,\dots\}
\end{align} \right.$

Then, $h$ is bijective because both $f$ and $g$ are bijective by definition.

Hence, $A \cup B$ is denumerable, as required.

However, this only works if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

So, in the case that $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint:

$A\cup B = A \cup (B-A)$ and $A \cap (B-A) = \emptyset$

I'm not sure what to do next.

If I can show that $B-A$ is denumerable, then I can use the above workings to conclude that $A\cup B$ is denumerable too. So I will attempt to construct a bijection $\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow B-A$:

I know that $(B-A)\subset B$, so, there exists an inclusion function $i:(B-A)\rightarrow B$, which is an injection. I thought of $g^{-1}\circ i$ but that's just an injection $(B-A) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z^+}$.

---

How can I build the required bijection ? I also would like to seek feedback if there are other parts of my work that could be written better.

Comment: When getting acquainted with the subject, one may want to show very soon that the existence of a surjection is enough when the set is infinite--then your function $h$ is enough to prove the claim.

Comment: I prefer to go from $A\cup B$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$. Use the inverse of your procedure to deal with any $a\in A$. Also to deal with any $b\in B\setminus A$. This gives a bijection to an infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$. Then map this infinite subset bijectively to $\mathbb{Z}^+$ by sending the $n$-th element to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with two bijections,

$\quad f:\mathbb{Z^+} \rightarrow A, \; g:\mathbb{Z^+} \rightarrow B$

we can use recursion to define a function $h:\mathbb{Z^+} \rightarrow A \cup B$ as follows:

Set $h(1) = f(1)$.

Assume $h$ has been defined on the segment $[1,n)$ with $n \ge 2$ and define
$$
h(n)=\begin{cases}
  f\bigr(\,\text{min}(\,f^{-1}\text{<}A \setminus h[1,n)\,\text{>})\,\bigr)\quad\text{if }n \text{ is odd}\\
  g\bigr(\,\text{min}(\,g^{-1}\text{<}B \setminus h[1,n)\,\text{>})\,\bigr)\quad\text{if }n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}
$$

So by [recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition) we've specified our function $h:\mathbb{Z^+} \rightarrow A \cup B$.

One can use induction to show that $h$ is injective.

One can use induction to show that the range of $h$ includes $A$.

One can use induction to show that the range of $h$ includes $B$.

So $h$ is a bijection.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ are not the empty set. Let $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow B$ be ennumerations of $A$ and $B$; that is, $f$ and $g$ are surjective functions from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $A$ and $B$, respectively. The function $h:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A\cup B$ defined by: for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$h(n)=\begin{cases}
  f(k)\quad\text{if }n=2k\\
  g(k)\quad\text{if }n=2k+1
\end{cases}$$

This proof is valid even when $A\cap B\not=\varnothing$; a point in their intersection might have several preimages, but as well as any other element in $A$ or $B$. There is no problem with the definition of $h$, and I think it is clear that $h$ is surjective.